# Writing a double array to a wave file in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, wav

I'm trying to write a wave file from scratch using c#. I managed to write 16 bit samples with no issue. But when it comes to 24 bit, apparently all bets are off.
I tried various ways of converting an int to a 3-byte array, which I would proceed to write to the data chunk L-L-L-R-R-R (as its a 24 bit stereo PCM wav).

For the 16bit part, I used this to generate the samples:

```
//numberOfBytes = 2 - for 16bit. slice = something like 2*Math.Pi*frequency/samplerate

    private static byte[,] BuildByteWave(double slice, int numberOfBytes=2)
                {
                    double dataPt = 0;
                    byte[,] output = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(Samples),numberOfBytes];

            for (int i = 0; i < Samples; i++)
            {
                dataPt = Math.Sin(i * slice) * Settings.Amplitude;
                int data = Convert.ToInt32(dataPt * Settings.Volume * 32767);
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfBytes; j++)
                {
                    output[i, j] = ExtractByte(data, j);
                }

            }
            return output;
        }
```

This returns an array I later use to write to the data chunk like so

```
writer.WriteByte(samples[1][0]); //write to the left channel
writer.WriteByte(samples[1][1]); //write to the left channel
writer.WriteByte(samples[2][0]); //now to the second channel
writer.WriteByte(samples[2][1]); //and yet again.
```

Where 1 and 2 represent a certain sine wave.
However, if I tried the above with numberOfBytes = 3, it fails hard. The wave is a bunch of non-sense. (the header is formatted correctly).

I understood that I need to convert int32 to int24 and that I need to "pad" the samples, but I found no concrete 24bit tutorial anywhere.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Edited for clarity.

Comment: To convert 32 bits to 24 bits you just ignore the low 8 bits. However, I'm not clear on how you are storing 32-bit samples in an `int[]`. Should it be `uint[]`? Or are they stored as positive and negative numbers somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `int24` - you will need to do it yourself.  `for/switch` is a bit of an anti-pattern, too.

```
int[] samples = /* samples scaled to +/- 8388607 (0x7f`ffff) */;
byte[] data = new byte[samples.Length * 3];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < samples.Length; i++, j += 3)
{
    // WAV is little endian
    data[j + 0] = (byte)((i >>  0) & 0xff);
    data[j + 1] = (byte)((i >>  8) & 0xff);
    data[j + 2] = (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xff);
}

// data now has the 24-bit samples.
```

As an example, here's a program ([Github](https://github.com/mgaffigan/WavGeneratorDemo)) which generates a [15 second 44.1kHz 24-bit stereo wav file with 440 Hz in the left channel and 1 kHz in the right channel](https://github.com/mgaffigan/WavGeneratorDemo/raw/master/example%20out.wav):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WavGeneratorDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        const int INT24_MAX = 0x7f_ffff;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int sampleRate = 44100;
            const int lengthInSeconds = 15 /* sec */;
            const int channels = 2;
            const double channelSamplesPerSecond = sampleRate * channels;
            var samples = new double[lengthInSeconds * sampleRate * channels];

            // Left is 440 Hz sine wave
            FillWithSineWave(samples, channels, channelSamplesPerSecond, 0 /* Left */, 440 /* Hz */);
            // Right is 1 kHz sine wave
            FillWithSineWave(samples, channels, channelSamplesPerSecond, 1 /* Right */, 1000 /* Hz */);

            WriteWavFile(samples, sampleRate, channels, "out.wav");
        }

        private static void WriteWavFile(double[] samples, uint sampleRate, ushort channels, string fileName)
        {
            using (var wavFile = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                const int chunkHeaderSize = 8,
                    waveHeaderSize = 4,
                    fmtChunkSize = 16;
                uint samplesByteLength = (uint)samples.Length * 3u;

                // RIFF header
                wavFile.WriteAscii("RIFF");
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt32(
                    waveHeaderSize
                    + chunkHeaderSize + fmtChunkSize
                    + chunkHeaderSize + samplesByteLength);
                wavFile.WriteAscii("WAVE");

                // fmt header
                wavFile.WriteAscii("fmt ");
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt32(fmtChunkSize);
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt16(1);               // AudioFormat = PCM
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt16(channels);
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt32(sampleRate);
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt32(sampleRate * channels);
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt16((ushort)(3 * channels));    // Block Align (stride)
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt16(24);              // Bits per sample

                // samples data
                wavFile.WriteAscii("data");
                wavFile.WriteLittleEndianUInt32(samplesByteLength);
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
                {
                    var scaledValue = DoubleToInt24(samples[i]);
                    wavFile.WriteLittleEndianInt24(scaledValue);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void FillWithSineWave(double[] samples, int channels, double channelSamplesPerSecond, int channelNo, double freq)
        {
            for (int i = channelNo; i < samples.Length; i += channels)
            {
                var t = (i - channelNo) / channelSamplesPerSecond;
                samples[i] = Math.Sin(t * (freq * Math.PI * 2));
            }
        }

        private static int DoubleToInt24(double value)
        {
            if (value < -1 || value > 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
            }

            return (int)(value * INT24_MAX);
        }
    }

    static class StreamExtensions
    {
        public static void WriteAscii(this Stream s, string str) => s.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));

        public static void WriteLittleEndianUInt32(this Stream s, UInt32 i)
        {
            var b = new byte[4];
            b[0] = (byte)((i >> 0) & 0xff);
            b[1] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xff);
            b[2] = (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xff);
            b[3] = (byte)((i >> 24) & 0xff);
            s.Write(b);
        }

        public static void WriteLittleEndianInt24(this Stream s, Int32 i)
        {
            var b = new byte[3];
            b[0] = (byte)((i >> 0) & 0xff);
            b[1] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xff);
            b[2] = (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xff);
            s.Write(b);
        }

        public static void WriteLittleEndianUInt16(this Stream s, UInt16 i)
        {
            var b = new byte[2];
            b[0] = (byte)((i >> 0) & 0xff);
            b[1] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xff);
            s.Write(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates:

[image: Screenshot of Adobe Audition zoomed into the sample view and spectral view showing a pure 1 kHz and 440 Hz tone at 0 dB]

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thank you for the link, I actually googled this like crazy, but to no avail. I now (kinda) understand what I did wrong. Cheers!